# How to pass more than one string into substr_count?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to pull out a bunch keywords from my last 200 tweets but so far using 'substr_count' only allows me to search one string at a time.

Is there a way to define an array of keywords and use 'substr_count' to count all of them for me?

```
$recentTweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=username');
GLOBAL $textDump;
for ($i=0; $i<count($recentTweets); $i++){
    $textDump .= $recentTweets[$i]->text . " ";
};
$keyWords = "the";
$number = substr_count(strtolower($textDump), strtolower($keyWords)); 
echo $number;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$textDump = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$keyWords = array("the", "fox");
foreach ($keyWords as $keyWord) {
    $number[$keyWord] = substr_count(strtolower($textDump), strtolower($keyWord));
}
print_r($number); // Array ( [the] => 2 [fox] => 1 )
```